# Trying to use execvp() in C with user input in unix

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, execvp

I'm trying to make a program that will prompt the user for a command, then use exec to execute that command.

For instance if they gave me "ls -la" I would have to execute that command. I've tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int ret, num_args;

    printf("Enter number of arguments (Example: \"ls -la\" has 1 argument): ");
    scanf("%d", &num_args);

    char *cmd[num_args];

    printf("Enter command name: ");
    scanf("%s", &cmd[0]);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_args; i++)
    {
            printf("Enter parameter: ");
            scanf("%s", &cmd[i]);
    }

    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
}
```

However, when I tried the following run it gave me a "segmentation fault"

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter number of arguments (Example: "ls -la" has 1 argument): 2
Enter command name: ls
Enter parameter: -la
Enter parameter: .
Segmentation fault
$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your implementation supports it you should use the safer `getline()` instead on `scanf()` or `fgets()`.  `getline()` will safely handle long lines and NULL characters.  It will allocate enough memory to fit the entire line.  `getline()` can allocate memory so you will have to free it yourself later on.

Here is the [glibc `getline()` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Line-Input).

Here is a quick modification to use getline (It still needs work, error checking and I haven't fully checked it for correctness yet):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    printf("Enter number of arguments (Example: \"ls -la\" has 1 argument): \n");

    char *num = NULL;
    size_t sz = 0;
    getline(&num, &sz, stdin);

    int num_args;
    sscanf(num, "%d", &num_args);

    char *cmd[num_args+2];
    memset(cmd, 0, sizeof(char*) * (num_args+2));

    printf("Enter command name: \n");


    int len = getline(&cmd[0], &sz, stdin); 

    cmd[0][len-1] = '\0';

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < num_args+1; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter parameter: \n");
        sz = 0;
        len = getline(&cmd[i], &sz, stdin);
        cmd[i][len-1] = '\0';
    }

    return execvp(cmd[0], cmd);

}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't seem to know what getline is, is this because of a missing #include line or just the compiler itself?

Comment: `getline` is a GNU function in C: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Comment: What compiler and what Operating System?

Comment: i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 (OS X 10.5.8)

Comment: It says:
Undefined symbols:
  "_getline", referenced from:
      _main in ccvpqdih.o
      _main in ccvpqdih.o
      _main in ccvpqdih.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Thank you! That latest version works just fine. I appreciate it man!

Comment: Great.  Make sure to read the getline() docs.  Also, make sure to check the getline() return value etc...

Comment: How did you get the compiler / linker to find getline()?

Comment: I didn't. I just tried it on a remote unix machine, so it must be something with darwin's compiler. Very strange..

Comment: Well, getline isn't standard or POSIX so maybe its just not available or you have to link a special library.  I'm not familiar with OS X.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for your strings.  The following line only allocates `num_args` worth of pointers to `char`:

```
char *cmd[num_args];
```

First of all, you'll be getting `num_args + 1` strings (don't forget that the command itself is `cmd[0]`).  The easiest way is to statically allocate the memory as an array of character buffers:

```
const unsigned int MAX_LEN = 512; // Arbitrary number
char cmd[num_args + 1][MAX_LEN];
```

However, now you can't use `scanf` to read in a line because the user could input a string that's longer than your character buffer.  Instead, you'll have to use `fgets`, which can limit the number of characters the user can input:

```
fgets(cmd[i], MAX_LEN, stdin);
```

Keep in mind that `fgets` also reads newline characters, so make sure to strip any stray ones that show up (but don't assume that they're there).

Comment: Trying it that way gave me a bunch of compiler errors. It's saying     cmd[num_arghs + 1][MAX_LEN]; isn't right: "syntax error before ';'"

Comment: @Nick Double check your code; I wrote a little test program and it compiled fine for me.

Comment: Woops, I forgot a semicolon on the `MAX_LEN = 512` line. Fixed now.

Comment: `scanf` can also limit the number of characters the user can input - use `"%511s"` if your buffer is of size 512, as in your example.

Comment: Oh, and if you do this you can't directly pass `cmd` to `execvp` anymore - it needs an array of pointers to char (terminated by a NULL entry), not an array of arrays of char (this is a good example of a case in which they're **not** equivalent).

Comment: Note that you need num_args + 2 string pointers; one for the command name, num_args for the arguments, and one for the terminating null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you need one more entry in the `argv` you pass to `execvp`, which has to be `(char *)NULL` to let it know that it's reached the end of the list.

Comment: And another one for argv[0] which is the name of the command (normally).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually allocated any memory for the strings pointed to by the cmd array.

Comment: So how exactly would I do this?

Comment: Look up malloc/free and make sure each pointer in "cmd" is allocated enough space.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the man page for scanf().  One of the neatest things it can do is automatically allocate the string buffers on the fly, you need to supply a pointer to a string instead of just passing the string and supply the %as format.

```
char *my_string;
scanf("%as", &my_string);
```

Then you don't need to bother with preallocating, don't need to bother with buffer overflows, etc.  Just remember to free() it after you're done with it.

Comment: The '`%as`' specification is _not_ standard C behaviour - useful though it may be.